# Show up website in google search

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

When user enter website searching key words it suppose to be seen in searching engine, but mine does not show in searching engine at all. What I have found is that meta tag can enable my site to show in search engine but that also still does do what I want yet

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="www.solutionholdings.com.my" content="solution engineering holdings berhad">
</head>
```

What shall I do to enable my site to show in search engine when key words are used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not control what you can show and what can not on google.

But you can make some checks.
See what google have **index from your site** by google that

```
site:www.solutionholdings.com.my  (return zero)
site:solutionholdings.com.my      (return 14 results)
```

So your site probably not indexed yet because is too young ? and google did not have the time to index it ? **Do you submit it to google** ?

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en_uk

Next go to the **google webmaster tools**, register your site and get more information's about the search and the index that you have so far

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

There are a lot of information's on this matter and hard to make your site to go up, or be found by search engines. I suggest to google "how do i get my website to show up on search engines" for more...

Answer (score 0):

Google have their own algorithm to fetch websites that is credible for what we search. We cannot control that but their are so many things we need to do so that the google crawl your website.

1. Create an account in GOOGLE WEBMASTERL TOOLS
2. in google webmaster tool create SITEMAP for your site
3. and lastly FETCH your URL so that the Google will crawl your site.

Their are so many tricks you can do so that the search engine can crawl your site. This are only the basic.

Answer (score 0):

Meta Elements describe the content of a Webpage, Search Engines will not understand this Meta Tag in your Code:

```
<meta name="www.solutionholdings.com.my" content="">
```

Use:

```
<meta name="description" content="">
```